# HDMI delay between monitor

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, delay

I want to play a video file on two different screens connected on an HDMI splitter which is connected itself to the video board.

The problem is that these two screens take a different amout of time to process the signal before displaying it.

I can measure a delay between 40 and 100ms to display a frame from one monitor to the other.

Usually this problem come with audio and the solution is to delay the audio but that is not the point here since we're only dealing with video signal.

I think the only solution it to delay the signal going to the fastest screen but I can not find any capable device.

Comment: Is it possible there is an issue with a slow videocard or poor driver? These seems pretty abnormal to me. I would try running a screen saver or other type of animation to confirm.

Comment: I used an HDMI splitter so the issue doesn't come from the video card.

Comment: One of the screen use "intelligent frame creation" witch explains the different processing delay.

Comment: You need to include more information as there are quite a few things that can affect transmission speeds.

Are the same (and proper) wall plates being used, are the lengths of cable the same?

Is one getting routed near power conduits, or otherwise running across supposedly shielded lines?

Are the lines crossing over at a 90 degree angle to such a power transmission line, or alongside it?

A lot of the things that you need to consider with network cabling you need to consider with HDMI cables, as it is not analog but digital signals and will degrade with signal strength.

Comment: My question is not "why is there a delay?", but "there is a known delay, how to solve it?". Anyway to answer your question, the two cables going out of the HDMI splitter are the same length and connect straightforward in my test labs so there is no interference. As said above the cause of the delay is that one of the screen has an "intelligent frame creation" feature.

Comment: @tinmaru If you know the intelligent frame creation is causing the delay, can't you disable the feature in the monitor's OSD?

Comment: No because I need it to have activated on one screen.

Comment: At the gym where I go they have large monitors in some of the exercise areas, and sometimes I can see three at once.  They are all the same brand/model, and often I'll observe three tuned to the same channel but not in visual sync -- off by maybe 200 ms.  Certainly part of this is the decompression logic not being in sync, but also keep in mind that the video must be buffered from the decompressed rasterized data to data that can feed the LCD shift registers.  This buffering may be several fields worth.

Comment: In this case the cause of the delay is well known: intelligent frame creation

Comment: I want to be able to display a signal in sync although the two tv have different delay. Basically I'm looking for a device that could delay the hdmi signal that I would plug on the fastest line. Any other input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> I think the only solution it to delay the signal going to the fastest
>   screen but I can not find any capable device.

The capable device might be the TV itself. With IFC enabled, it is inserting additional frames in an effort to eliminate display motion blur and smooth what you see. This is an option that can be disabled from your TV's options menu usually under ***picture*** options / Advanced setting.
Depending on your model, you may have the options - On/Off, Low, Mid, High.

It may look something like the attached image.

[image: IFC menu]

Comment: One tv has intelligent frame creation and the other not. Has I said in the comment I need this feature to stay on. The other monitor is a simple hdmi screen and has not this kind of option.

Comment: I seet that in your comments now, there was some time from my posting to your updated comment.

Comment: This did the trick for my delay.  On my Sharp TV, this was under the Advanced Picture Settings as Motion Enhancement.